# Deleting all files except some from a folder using applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an Apple script to delete all the contents of a folder except one file (stage.txt). This is the script I've written:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists folder "~/Library/Application Support/ABC/CS" then
        delete (every item of folder "~/Library/Application Support/ABC/CS" whose name is not "stage.txt")
    end if
end tell
```

But I am getting the following error: "System Events got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000

Please help.

PS: If anyone knows any good tutorial to get started on Apple Script, kindly comment that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it this way:

```
(*
Apple Scritp to Delete Files in all Startup and auto-launch Folders
    with dialog box to choose Delete or Cancel
    Uwe @UweTheSailor May 2022
    
    Exception handling for Roguea files (the Piezo App)
    added by Uwe in July 2022
*)

-- Variable Declaration Launch Deamons
set xyz to alias "Macintosh HD:Library:LaunchDaemons:"
-- Counter i increment to repeat loop (for loop)
set i to 1
set listOfNames to {}
set ItemNr to 0
set RmFile to 0

-- Loop all folders and check if there are files in the Startup and Launch Folders:
repeat until i = 4
    -- empty the list before filling it up again!
    set listOfNames to {}
    -- Fill the List "listOfNames" with files in the folder:
    tell application "Finder"
        set filelist to every file of the xyz
        repeat with currentFile in filelist
            set currentFileName to (the name of currentFile)
            -- exception for the two files, do not copy into list and do not remove from folder
            if currentFileName ≠ "com.rogueamoeba.aceagent.plist" and currentFileName ≠ "com.rogueamoeba.acetool.plist" then
                copy currentFileName to the end of listOfNames
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" " & return}
                set ItemNr to ItemNr + 1
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    -- Only show dialog when Folder is empty (=content of listOfNames is Zero)!
    if length of listOfNames = 0 then
        display dialog "    There are " & length of listOfNames & " files in the folder: 
    " & xyz with title "Folder is empty!" default button "OK" giving up after 5
        
        -- Only offer Delete if there are files in the folder! 
    else if length of listOfNames > 0 then
        -- Display a dialog window with buttons and auto Cancel if no interaction after 10 seconds:
        set theButton to button returned of (display dialog "The Folder contains " & length of listOfNames & " files as follows: 
" & listOfNames with title "Found Files in the " & xyz with icon caution buttons {"Cancel", "Delete"} default button "Cancel" giving up after 5)
        -- Move all Files to the Bin if Button Delete is pressed
        if theButton is "Delete" then
            tell application "Finder"
                repeat until ItemNr = 0
                    delete (item ItemNr of (xyz))
                    set ItemNr to ItemNr - 1
                end repeat
            end tell
        end if
    end if
    
    -- Increment i + 1 and move to the next folder
    set i to i + 1
    -- Update the variable xyz to the next folder
    if i = 2 then
        set xyz to alias "Macintosh HD:Library:StartupItems:"
    else if i = 3 then
        set xyz to alias "Macintosh HD:Library:LaunchAgents:"
    end if
end repeat
```

I hope this helps you to understand how to handle exceptions. I am sure there are more sophisticated ways to do that, but for me this is good enough.
Cheers!